# how to create a send to browse function in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer

Is it possible to create a browse function in the 'send to' folder in windows 7? It would be convenient to be able to search for a custom destination when moving various items.

Comment: Browse what/where ?

Comment: @Sathya: I assume the OP means a Save File dialog shows up. Kind of a "Send To..." menu item.

Answer (score 0):

First, according to [Howto-geek](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-7/stupid-geek-tricks-secret-items-on-the-windows-7-send-to-menu/), updating send to menu is easier than ever.

Second, according to [the same source](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows/add-copy-to-move-to-to-the-windows-explorer-right-click-menu/), it is quite easy (although requiring a bit of regedit magick) to add a move to/copy to item to right click menu.